# Hibernate - Get the last element of a ScrollableResults with ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

Simple java batch reading millions of rows using JPA/Hibernate. My question is: how I can identify the last result in a `ScrollableResults` with `ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY`?

Using `isLast()` method it's not an option with the forward only scroll mode, and using ScrollMode.SCROLL_INSENSITIVE degrades the performance of my batch.

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.ScrollMode;
import org.hibernate.ScrollableResults;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.StatelessSession;

StatelessSession statelessSession = ((Session) em.getDelegate()).getSessionFactory().openStatelessSession();
Query query = statelessSession.createSQLQuery("MY_QUERY")
                        .setReadOnly(true)
                        .setFetchSize(Integer.valueOf(1000));
ScrollableResults results = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
while (results.next()) {
...
//I need to extract a timestamp from the last record here
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a query that just obtains the last result instead.

Comment: No, because I also need the other rows and an extra query just to get the last element add too much overhead to an already heavy batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you though about this "basic" way of doing it  (and if it is the case, why it is not working ?) :

```
ScrollableResults results = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

Timestamp ts = null;
while (results.next()) {
    ...
    //I need to extact a timestamp from the last record here
    ts = results.getTimestamp("timestamp_column");
}

// you'll have here ts with the value of the latest row.
// Be careful, it can be null in case of empty result set.
```

Comment: Damn, I haven't thought about this, I will simply move the logic related to that timestamp past the loop and keep updating ts value each time until the end. Thank you very much.

Comment: This reads every record though, when you only want the last. Is there a better way or does a call to `.last()` essentially enumerate the entire query as well?

Comment: @JoshM.yes : reverse the order of the query, limit 1, grab the row :)